# Send chunked response from microhttpd

Tags: c, http, gnu

I am using GNU microhttpd lib in my project,
And i want to send a [chunked response to the client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at this example https://gnunet.org/svn/libmicrohttpd/src/examples/fileserver_example.c specifically on the use of function MHD_create_response_from_callback which i what i think that you are looking for